# Python strip and Counter for top 3 alphabets

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections, counter, strip

The output should be top 3 letters from the given input, but I am unable to remove the whitespace even after using strip function over the input.
Code :

```
    from collections import Counter
    insider = input("Enter the input you wanna enter : ")
    actual = insider.strip()
    count = Counter()
    for i in actual:
        count[i]+=1
    print(count.most_common(3))
```

OUTPUT:

```
    Enter the input you wanna enter : is this the ral life or is it just fantasy
    [(' ', 9), ('i', 5), ('s', 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

strip will only remove leading and trailing whitespaces.

You can remove the whitespaces using replace:

```
actual = insider.replace(' ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `insider.strip()` use `("").join(insider.split())`. The `split` method will remove the whitespace from the string and convert it into a list, from which you can convert it to string using `("").join(str)`.

Your code now becomes

```
from collections import Counter
insider = input("Enter the input you wanna enter : ")
actual = ("").join(insider.split())
count = Counter()
for i in actual:
    count[i]+=1
print(count.most_common(3))
```

which gives

```
Enter the input you wanna enter : is this the ral life or is it just fantasy
[('i', 5), ('s', 5), ('t', 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `''.join(s.split())` to remove whitespace character. And then construct counter from it directly.

```
from collections import Counter

s = input("Enter the input you wanna enter : ")

s = ''.join(s.split())

print(counter = Counter(s))

counter.most_common(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I guess the code cannot be shorter than this?

```
from collections import Counter
insider = input("Enter the input you wanna enter : ").lower()
actual = ''.join(insider.split())
print(Counter(actual).most_common(3))
```